# Keyboard stopped working on 15.10

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

I recently restarted after an update on 15.10, and now the keyboard on my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga) doesn't work. I can't even ctrl-alt-[N] to get to a virtual terminal, nor does a USB keyboard work. The keyboard *does* work in BIOS setup and GRUB mode, but that's it. Also, the touchscreen stopped working at the same time. I had also changed a line in a xorg.conf.d file, affecting the synaptics driver prior to this, but I can't work out why this would kill the keyboard and touchscreen.

Answer (score 0):

OK; looks like the xorg.conf.d file was the problem; I dropped into a recovery boot and reverted that file. When it had the line `Driver "synaptics"` under InputClass the keyboard no longer worked. Reverting this to `MatchDriver` that was there previously (And I think is in error) meant I've got keyboard again.

Answer (score 0):

In my ubuntu 14.04 keyboard was working up to the grub menu, after that it stopped responding.
apart from this, my network also not working.

So, I have restarted ubuntu in recovery mode and selected a different kernel.
Now both keyboard and network start working.

What I understood from this is - my latest kernel failed to load these modules.